# Link display: function connected to added worksheet from particular location

Tags: excel, vba

I created add-in with a few options, e.g.:

- Add sheet with exchange rates("TPD value")
- Function for assign date to currency based on mentioned sheet.

It works very well during use but if I send file to another add-in user the functions looks like:
`='C:\TrustedVBA\AddRates_1.2.xlam'!ExRate(Q2,L2)`  (link to added sheet) instead of `=ExRate(Q2,L2)`

Any idea how to get expected format (`=ExRate(Q2,L2)`) on each computer?

Full function code:

```
Function ExRate(TCurr, TPD As Range) As Variant

Dim TPD_Value As Worksheet

Set TPD_Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TPD value")

Dim RateTable As Range

Dim Location1 As Range

Dim ColumnNo As Integer

Select Case TCurr

            Case Is = "EUR": ExRate = 1

Case Else

        On Error Resume Next

            Set RateTable = TPD_Value.Columns("A:AP")

            Set Location1 = TPD_Value.Cells.Find(What:=TCurr, LookAt:=xlWhole,

            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                ColumnNo = Location1.Column

       On Error Resume Next

            ExRate = Application.VLookup(TPD, RateTable, ColumnNo, False)

End Select

End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"if I send file to another add-in user"*?

Comment: I work for corporation - when I'm opening file where someone used my function (enterd on other computer) I see *='C:\TrustedVBA\AddRates_1.2.xlam'!ExRate(Q2,L2)*
instead
*=ExRate(Q2,L2)*